# Problem in opening file

Tags: 12.04

When I use "locate filename", it's path is shown in terminal, but when I try to open it using that path it doesn't get opened. Even it is not displayed with ls or ls -a command. 
Can somebody help me ??

```
enter code here
```

priyanka@priyanka-SVS13112ENS:~$ locate *.hs

/home/priyanka/hskl.hs

/home/priyanka/hskl2.hs

/home/priyanka/hsklas.hs

/home/priyanka/parser1.hs

/home/priyanka/try.hs

priyanka@priyanka-SVS13112ENS:~$ ls /home/priyanka/

Desktop

Comment: Please add an example to the question.

Comment: Be careful about lowercase and UPPERCASE. In Ubuntu (unlike Windows) a file is not the same as a File, of a fIle. If the file name or folder names have spaces, use double quote at the beginning and end of the "my path/file".

Answer (score 2):

The `locate` command uses a database that is only updated once per day by default. So it is possible the files are showing up even though they have already been removed. To list only files that actually exist, you can either add the `-e` option

```
locate -e '*.hs'
```

or (if you have sufficient privileges), update the database with

```
sudo updatedb
```

Comment: So, is there no way to recover them ?? I run the following command  ""set backupdir = ./.backup, . , /tmp" that do the great disaster.